# Outputting DHCP script into body of email

Tags: email, powershell, output, dhcp

I have asked a question similar to the one I'm about to post. I tried using the solution to create my own version but I've had no success. I have the below script that I have found on another website and it's perfect for what I'm looking for, but rather the output be sent in as the body of the email rather than output to a file. How would I go about doing it? Also if anyone has the patience to explain a little It would be greatly appreciated :).

```
$a = (netsh dhcp server 172.20.102.1 scope 172.20.104.0 show clients 1)

$lines = @()

foreach ($i in $a){
    if ($i -match "\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"){
        If ($i -match "[0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}"){    
            $lines += $i.Trim()
        }
    }
}
$csvfile = @()

foreach ($l in $lines){
    $Row = "" | select Hostname,IP
    $l = $l -replace '[0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}[:-][0-9a-f]{2}', ''
    $l = $l -replace ' - ',','
    $l = $l -replace '\s{4,}',''
    $l = $l -replace '--','-'
    $l = $l -replace '-D-','-'
    $l = $l -replace '[-]{1}\d{1,2}[/]\d{1,2}[/]\d{4}',''
    $l = $l -replace '\d{1,2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2}',''
    $l = $l -replace 'AM',''
    $l = $l -replace 'PM',''
    $l = $l -replace '\s{1}',''
    $l = $l + "`n"
    $l = $l -replace '[,][-]',','
    $Row.IP = ($l.Split(","))[0]
    #Subnet mask not used, but maybe later
    #$Row.SubNetMask = ($l.Split(","))[1]
    $Row.Hostname = ($l.Split(","))[2]
    $csvfile += $Row
}


$csvfile | sort-object Hostname | Export-Csv "Out_List.csv"


$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "body {margin: 10px; width: 600px; font-family:arial; font-size: 12px;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: rgb(179,179,179);align='left';}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 2px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: white;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"


$html = $csvfile | sort-object Hostname | ConvertTo-HTML | out-string 
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "exchange" -Body $html -BodyAsHtml -From "DHCP@.com.au" -To "@.com.au" -Subject "DHCP Report"
```

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try:

```
$html = $csvfile | sort-object Hostname | ConvertTo-HTML | out-string
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "mail server" -Body $html -BodyAsHtml -From "noreply@mailserver.com.au" -To "me@mailserver.com" -Subject "DHCP Report"
```

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: I get:
Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.

I'll fiddle a bit and see if I can make it work, but I'm pretty rubbish with PS.

Comment: $html = $csvfile | sort-object Hostname | ConvertTo-HTML | out-string

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> $html | gm
   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject

PS C:\Windows\system32> $html | Out-String | gm
   TypeName: System.String

out-string should convert it to a string for you.

Comment: The $html I used above was 
$html = invoke-webrequest -uri www.google.com
That's why it was of type:
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject

Comment: Ooooh It's working, but I get an error at the same time - 
Get-Member : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HtmlWebResponseObject'.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I might have confused you. I hit enter and my commented added before I meant it to. Your command could be:
$html = $csvfile | sort-object Hostname | ConvertTo-HTML | out-string
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer "mail server" -Body $html -BodyAsHtml -From "noreply@mailserver.com.au" -To "me@mailserver.com" -Subject "DHCP Report"

Comment: I put the get-member bits in to show you the types that were being outputted from the different cmdlets being piped to each other. I have updated my answer as to what it should look like. That should work.

Comment: Sorry, I've not had the chance to try it. I think I've broken it, either that or powershell upgrade broke it. I've edited my original to show you what I have, but it's just giving me a blank email now :(

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to @Tim's answer:

you can even add CSS to the converted html like this :

```
$style = @"
<style>
table {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
</style>
"@
$html =import-Csv "Out_List.csv" |ConvertTo-Html -head $style |out-string
```

Comment: I get the:
Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.

I've probably broken it xD.

Comment: I tried adding the |out-string after googling about. Unfortunately not working. For your fix though, am I just pasting that in under the html formatting?

Comment: @rdd2 Can you update the question with your modified script and error?